# How can I solve this PDE using change of variables?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am currently struggling with this PDE:
$$
(xy-x)u_x-(y^2+2x^2)u_y=0
$$
with the boundary condition
$$
u(0,0)=0.
$$
I have tried expressing it as 
$$
\langle u_x,u_y\rangle \cdot \langle xy-x,-y^2-2x^2\rangle = 0
$$
Where the directional derivative of the function $u(x,y)$ is zero along the characteristic curves described by the differential equation
$$
\frac{dy}{dx} = -\frac{y^2+2x^2}{x(y-1)}
$$
However, the above is not separable, and I have attempted to find certain integrating factors but haven't had any luck. Can the PDE be solved with a change of variables?

Comment: One solution is $u(x,y)=0$. Is that enough? Usually a boundary condition is specified along a line or curve.

Comment: Bob, this question actually came up as a result of looking for a Lyapunov function for a non-linear system. The system had a typo in it, which is why I had so much trouble finding one without resorting to this. By the definition of a Lyapunov function, u(x,y)=0 won't work. But that's alright, I just thought it might be an interesting or challenging problem to post, thanks for the reply!